# Convert a matrix of strings into a matrix of integers in python

Tags: python, string, matrix, integer

i have the following problem, i generate a matrix with this code

```
g = open("text.txt", "r")
inte=int(g.readline())
for x in itertools.islice(g, inte):
  maze.append(x.rstrip('\n').split(' '))
print(maze)
```

it produces something like this

```
[['1,', '0,', '0,', '0'], ['1,', '1,', '0,', '1'], ['1,', '1,', '0,', '0'], ['0,', '1,', '1,', '1']]
```

but i would like it to produce something like this instead

```
[[1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this? It would be look good if you replace string which containing character that is not a number into empty space before below statement.

```
list(map(lambda x: list(map(lambda y: int(y.replace(',', '')), x)), a))
```